# Python list contents error

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
for x in os.listdir("/home/"):
print x
```

> error:   File "./p1", line 4
>       print x
>           ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block
>
> Python 2.7.12

Comment: that could be an `IndentationError` in line 4. at the `print` statement. where there should be an 'indented block', just what the error message states. what is unclear about that?

Comment: What is unclear about that error? You didn't indent `print x`

Comment: python is exactly telling you that in line 4, the instruction `print x` has an indentation error. It cannot be more specific

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I replaced the target with a more relevant one.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Much better, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indent your code properly:

```
import os
for x in os.listdir("/home/"):
    print x
```

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: It's just a rendering artefact because Sim used the wrong Markdown.

Comment: import os
for x in os.listdir("/home/"):
    print x

Thank you

Comment: @antony_sebastian ??